# Is it preferred to answer questions without code reference or exemplification?

Tags: discussion

Most of the questions I've asked have been answered with theoretical, sometimes vague solutions, without any proper code example or reference. Is this preferred to answering with exemplification or code reference?

Comment: No, it is preferred to give a good, quality answer. I find that answers that include code samples get more upvotes; clearly people feel that answers *with* code are preferred.

Comment: When I look for a solution, a code sample says a thousand words. This doesn't mean that I want pure code though: knowing why you do something in the code or what some obscure call does is important.

Comment: It all depends. Sometimes people "just want that damn code", other times people complain about answers that "just give code and don't teach anything". It really depends.

Comment: Out of your 10 questions you can't interpolate that *"most"* have been answered vaguely. Some of your inquiries ask a bit generically for approach directions, so naturally won't be answered with code samples. Rather than prematurely accepting answers, edit your post if you require specific topic clarification.

Comment: Related: [Should an answer contain a SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188959)

Comment: A good code example can explain a lot, but there is an art to writing good code examples - just putting any old code in is not helpful.  Some of the criticisms of answering with code can be addressed with style of example code, e.g. giving a general structure but putting in // ADD YOUR BEHAVIOUR HERE for the details leaves the poster some problem solving to do.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'm sorry.. but as for what you've been noticing, really:

#### You should ask better questions

If you check the questions you speak of, **whenever you provided clear code, you got code back**, in every single answer that provided practical code - a practical and good answer has been received back.

In questions that provided lacking pseudo code, or an unclear question, you have received no code, or lacking code back.

The rest of your questions are unclear.

That said: Answers should be as clear as possible, sometimes code is relevant, sometimes it is not. There is no clear cut rule for what's the best way to explain something. A lot of good answers contain code and some don't. Including code often helps but is not a must.

---

Appendix A:

Let's look at these questions:

- [Javascript Formula Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20263921/1348195) has a clear code solution to your posted code, and in fact is a syntax error and should not have been asked to begin with.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370157/various-field-types-import-from-ods-to-mysql has no answer, and frankly I find it very unclear, and it should be clarified.
- [Android Studio not finding Sources from Phonegap Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21020988/1348195) has no code on your end (in the question) and has a code-less answer. This makes sense since it was asked about where to find a file..
- [Get line from text file - php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524732/get-line-from-text-file-php) has code on the question part, and code in the answer.
- [If function succesful, then repeat function - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552026/if-function-succesful-then-repeat-function-php) has code on the question part, and in the answer. It's also closed as unclear, not *enough* code was provided in the question.
- [phpLDAP filter dn & uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013314/phpldap-filter-dn-uid) has code on the question part and in the answer.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481123/what-are-ldap-smart-cards-and-how-are-they-used is offtopic and honestly it's unclear what's being asked.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762022/apache-ldap-authentication-error is completely unclear and lacks any information to diagnose the problem.
- [Generate input submit for each column from sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058626/generate-input-submit-for-each-column-from-sql-table) has code on the question end and in the answer, although the accepted answer has the code not formatted.
- [Three simultaneous SQL queries in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23694040/1348195) is rather clueless to be fair, for example " I know multi-threading is no longer possible in PHP" is simply false (look at php pthreads), and is generally low quality, again - it has no concrete code and no concrete code in the answer.

Comment: Looking at the question titles - you shouldn't attempt to tag your questions in the title itself. This has little benefit. Instead use the [tagging system](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum Regarding my LDAP Smart Card question: What is the difference between that question and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663402/what-are-the-differences-between-ldap-and-active-directory?rq=1 ? How is mine too broad and that one not? And what exactly isn't clear? 

This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066421/writing-a-new-line-to-file-in-php is also a syntax error. It has 22 upvotes. Mine was just downvoted to -1. What is the difference?

Comment: @razvan.peter Some older questions are not good examples of what is on-topic these days. Back in '09, that question may have been acceptable and up-voted accordingly. It's off-topic now and I've voted to close. People also up-vote off-topic questions simply because they found it useful, even if it is on the wrong site.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, you should (must?) include a good, simple, illustrative code example in your answer when it's relevant and reasonably possible. If the question is vague, you can also clarify it with code. This is a site from **programmers** - programmers are supposed to write and understand **code**.

> **A picture speaks a thousand words.**

For programmers, code is like a picture.

Comment: But with all pictures, they themselves do not constitute the entire story.

Comment: @Makoto - I said _include_ :-)

Comment: Yes, a picture is an apt metaphor. You would never include a picture without a *caption*, would you?

Comment: @CodyGray Captions are especially important if half your audience is blind.

Comment: And please don't include a picture of your code